# Theory behind this natural sequential estimator of the mean

Tags: estimation, estimators, sequential-analysis

Suppose we have i.i.d. real random variables $X_1, \cdots$. We want to estimate the expectation $E[X_1]$ to within some desired error $\epsilon$, but we do not know the variance. We want to use as few samples as possible.

Consider the following estimator. In the $t$-th step, we look at $X_1, \cdots, X_t$, compute an estimate of the variance, and if the variance estimate corresponds to error $\ll \epsilon$ (say, by Chebyshev's inequality), then we return the average of $X_1, \cdots, X_t$, and otherwise we continue with the $t+1$-th step.

It is not hard to come up with a counterexample, showing that this estimator can fail in giving $\pm \epsilon$ approximation of $E[X]$. Still, is this something that has been studied? Can one prove some useful statistical properties of this estimator or something similar? I am thinking of properties such that under some assumptions, this estimator with indeed return an $\pm \epsilon$ approximation of $E[X]$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_analysis ?

Comment: I have gone through the article and I don't see any reference to this specific estimator. Am I missing something?